# TabCtrl_SetItemSize and user drawn tab controls

Tags: windows, winapi, resize, tabs

I have this Win32 user-drawn tab control that is created as:

```
    CONTROL "Tab1",IDC_TAB_CONT,"SysTabControl32",TCS_BOTTOM | 
            TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | NOT WS_VISIBLE,0,14,185,88
```

I'd like for this control to have its tabs resize as never to have to see the "*sliding arrows*":

[image]

Now, pretty much everything about this control works as expected, except for that fact that it won't respond to `TabCtrl_SetItemSize`. Try as I may, the size I get for the tabs when I get to draw them (in the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` passed to `WM_DRAWITEM`) is always the size that fits the longest caption in them and never the size I've set with `TabCtrl_SetItemSize`.

However, in the [`TabCtrl_SetItemSize` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760694(VS.85).aspx), it says that:

> [`TabCtrl_SetItemSize`] sets the width and height of tabs in a
>   fixed-width or **owner-drawn tab**
>   control.

The only way I've managed to have a decent resizing is by setting a dummy string of the desired length in it by sending the control a `TCM_SETITEM` message, and writing the desired text in it at draw time. This is rather inconvenient and not a particularly nice hack.

Is there anybody who would know

1. Why `TabCtrl_SetItemSize` isn't working as expected? and/or
2. How to set the tab size properly?

Many thanks,

joce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Setting `TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style is not enough, you have also to add `TCS_FIXEDWIDTH` style.
- The minimum size of a tab is at least icon width + 3 if icon is present.
  If you have icons (imageList attached to tabControl), you might get those "sliding arrows" even with fixed width (if there is less space available than: number of tabs*(icon width+3)